# Unable to get activity instance from work item

Tags: 2013, workflow

I'm using Tridion 2013 SP1. I'm getting below error while finishing an automatic activity from a decision activity.

Here is my code:

```
var session = new Session();
WorkItem  m_WorkItem = session.GetObject(workitemid) as WorkItem;
ActivityInstance currentactivity = m_WorkItem.Activity as ActivityInstance;
IEnumerable<ActivityDefinition> ieActivities = currentactivity.ActivityDefinition.ProcessDefinition.ActivityDefinitions;
ActivityDefinition activityInstance = ieActivities.ToList().Where(c => c.Title == "Publish EN to Testing and Staging").First();
DecisionActivityFinish finish = new DecisionActivityFinish(activityInstance, session.User, "Publish EN to Testing and Staging", session);
currentactivity.Finish(finish);
```

Error on the event viewer is like this,

> Unable to get activity instance from work item.
>   caused by: WorkItem.ActivityInstance

and description:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tcm:Error xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0" ErrorCode="D" Category="18" Source="Kernel" Severity="1">
    <tcm:Line Cause="false" MessageID="16138"><![CDATA[Unable to get ActivityInstance of Workflow work item (tcm:3-125-131200).]]><tcm:Token>RESID_4485</tcm:Token>
        <tcm:Token>ActivityInstance</tcm:Token>
        <tcm:Token>RESID_15212</tcm:Token>
        <tcm:Token>tcm:3-125-131200</tcm:Token>
    </tcm:Line>
    <tcm:Line ErrorCode="D" Cause="true"><![CDATA[Type mismatch]]></tcm:Line>
    <tcm:Details>
        <tcm:CallStack>
            <tcm:Location>WorkItem.ActivityInstance</tcm:Location>
            <tcm:Location>WorkItem.ActivityInstance</tcm:Location>
        </tcm:CallStack>
    </tcm:Details>
</tcm:Error>
```

[image: Workflow diagram]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, it's going wrong while casting

```
ActivityInstance currentactivity = m_WorkItem.Activity as ActivityInstance;
```

Try changing to

```
ActivityInstance currentactivity = (ActivityInstance)m_WorkItem.Activity;
```

### Update:

For **Automatic Activities**, you should use **Core Services**.

### Example:

```
WorkItemData mWorkItemData = (WorkItemData)mClient.Read(workItemId, mReadOptions);
ActivityInstanceData mCurrentActivity = (ActivityInstanceData)mClient.Read(mWorkItemData.Activity.IdRef, mReadOptions);
TridionActivityDefinitionData mTridionActivityDefinition = (TridionActivityDefinitionData)mClient.Read(mCurrentActivity.ActivityDefinition.IdRef, mReadOptions);
ProcessDefinitionData mProcessDefinition = (ProcessDefinitionData)mClient.Read(mTridionActivityDefinition.ProcessDefinition.IdRef, mReadOptions);
IList<ActivityDefinitionData> mActivityDefinitionList = new List<ActivityDefinitionData>(mProcessDefinition.ActivityDefinitions);

ActivityDefinitionData mNextActivity = (ActivityDefinitionData)mActivityDefinitionList.Where(c => c.Title == "Publish EN to Testing and Staging").FirstOrDefault();

if (mNextActivity != null)
{
    DecisionActivityFinishData mDecisionActivityFinishData = new DecisionActivityFinishData
    {
        NextActivity = new LinkToActivityDefinitionData { IdRef = mNextActivity.Id }
    };
    mClient.FinishActivity(mCurrentActivity.Id, mDecisionActivityFinishData, mReadOptions);
}
```

*Note: I have not tested above code, just wrote for you.*

Comment: Thanks Siva your code is perfectly running and my problem also solved.thanks again

Comment: Siva how to check in which context the item is originally created after localize in core service??

Comment: That sounds like a different question - please open a new question instead of burying it in the comments...

Answer (score 3):

Here a sample using an External Activity source code.

```
ProcessDefinitionData ProcessDefinition = (ProcessDefinitionData)CoreServiceClient.Read(ProcessInstance.ProcessDefinition.IdRef, ReadOptions);

ActivityDefinitionData NextActivity = (ActivityDefinitionData)CoreServiceClient.Read(ProcessDefinition.ActivityDefinitions.Where(w => w.Title.IndexOf("Publish EN to Testing and Staging") != -1).ElementAt(0).Id, ReadOptions);

CoreServiceClient.FinishActivity(ActivityInstance.Id, new DecisionActivityFinishData() {
        Message = "Finish Message",
        NextAssignee = GetNextAssignee(), 
        NextActivity = new LinkToActivityDefinitionData() { IdRef = NextActivity.Id }
    }, 
new ReadOptions());
```

Notice that I don't need to write code to get the current Activity Instance since it is already available in the `ActivityInstance` property as well as for the `CoreServiceClient` object.

As answered above, you shouldn't use the TOM .NET API to manipulate Workflow Objects unless you are doing it in an **Event System**. If your intention is to run that code in an Automatic Activity (C# or External) you must use Core Services.

Comment: +1 And definitely should not be creating TOM.NET sessions in your code, that's asking for trouble.